# libcurl outputting extra trailing bytes when downloading file

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I'm having a bit of a strange problem with `libcurl`. Essentially, while downloading a file from an HTTP server, it's outputting some garbage bytes at the end of the file. Whereas the file *should* be 1,710,017 bytes, the library instead writes 1,712,128, i.e. 2,111 more. I suspect it's some sort of buffering issue, as the latter number is a multiple of 2^12 (and 2^13, but it conforms to multiples of 2^12 in other cases). The extra data is either a respective number of bytes read from another part of the file (it only seems to read from one of 4 addresses each time, all towards the end), or in one case the byte `CD` repeated 2,111 times.

Relevant code:

```
std::string url; // defined elsewhere
FILE* data; // initialized elsewhere with option "wb"
CURL* query = curl_easy_init();

curl_easy_setopt(query, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, data);
curl_easy_setopt(query, CURLOPT_URL, url);
curl_easy_setopt(query, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_easy_setopt(query, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(query);
```

Also: the same issue occurs when using a simple write callback, and the issue occurs with any given remote server, not just this particular one.

**Edit #1:** I can only replicate this on Windows (tested on two machines with the same library files). It works on Debian.

**Edit #2:** It also occurs when `libcurl` is built on my laptop. To provide additional context, I am building from Marc Hörsken's ZIP (available from the official curl downloads page) using a VC14 environment on Windows 10.

Comment: Have you looked at this https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html?

Comment: @NulledPointer I don't see the relevance? Also, check the last edit to the OP.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any issue with the code, and since it only occurs when compiled on a particular machine, I'd say that machine uses some buggy version of libcurl

Comment: @AndreyTurkin I tried rebuilding `curl` from scratch, and the bug still occurs. I'll do some more testing tomorrow with my laptop to see if I can narrow down the issue and update the OP if I find anything new.

Comment: The docs say "By default, this is a FILE * to stdout." which leads me to suspect it is expecting a windows stream which will have different handling for \n. Are there 2111 instances of \n in the file? You may need to override CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION and make sure it handles the data as binary.

Comment: It's a binary file, and `fopen` is instructed to treat it as such. In any case, I still believe it's something to do with buffering because of its tendency to "round up" to a multiple of 2^12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm chalking this up to some weird VC bug or otherwise anomalous behavior. Rewriting the problem code to use an `fstream` instead of a `FILE` did the trick.